# Change color system for part of a document?

Tags: color

Is there a way to change the color model to `monochrome` for a section of a document? I would like to make a section `mononcrome` **without** affecting the headers. Is this possible? I know about `\usepackage[mononcrome]{xcolor}` and `\passOptionToPackage[mononcrome]{xcolor}` but these can only be applied in the preamble, and I *think* they affect the headers as well?

### MWE below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr,xcolor}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{}
\chead{\textcolor{red}{\leftmark}}
\lhead{\textcolor{blue}{Keep colors in header}}

\begin{document}

\section{Colors}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Monochrome}

\lipsum[3]\textcolor{red}{This should become gray}
\lipsum[4]\textcolor{green}{this too}
\lipsum[5]\textcolor{blue}{and this}

\section{Colors}

\lipsum[5]\textcolor{red}{This should stay red}
\lipsum[66]\textcolor{orange}{same with this}
\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `monochrome` does not convert colors into grayscale, but instead all colors are turned into black. For grayscale you can use the `gray` package option - however that does not seem so easy to switch as the `monochrome` setting as demonstrated in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I looked in the `xcolor` package and found what was executed by the `monochrome` option.  I then just placed it directly in the document in a group-limited way.

EDITED to make it into the `monochrome` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr,xcolor}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\rhead{}
\chead{\textcolor{red}{\leftmark}}
\lhead{\textcolor{blue}{Keep colors in header}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{monochrome}
{\begingroup
\colors@false
    \def\set@color{\c@lor@special\m@ne
      {color push \current@color}\aftergroup\reset@color}%
    \def\reset@color{\c@lor@special\m@ne{color pop}}%
    \def\set@page@color{\c@lor@special\m@ne{background \current@color}}
}
{\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Colors}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Monochrome}

\begin{monochrome}
\lipsum[3]\textcolor{red}{This should become gray}
\lipsum[4]\textcolor{green}{this too}
\lipsum[5]\textcolor{blue}{and this}
\end{monochrome}

\section{Colors}

\lipsum[5]\textcolor{red}{This should stay red}
\lipsum[66]\textcolor{orange}{same with this}
\lipsum[75]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that it would seem the monochrome portion has no grayscale, but is merely black.  But that still may be useful to the OP.

Comment: I agree, and the OP also asked for the `monochrome` option specifically, that's why I commented on his question and not on your answer (which is very nice, +1).

Comment: Not really suited to write a book on QCD, but who cares? ;-)

Comment: Hi, is it possible to make everything grayscale instead of monochrome? I thought monochrome was grayscale, because of my poor english =(

Answer (score 0):

To help with the discussion under Steven B. Segletes's answer, and since I can't comment there, here's how to set grayscale within a group `\selectcolormodel{gray}`, or as an environment:

```
\newenvironment{grayscale}
{\begingroup \selectcolormodel{gray}}
{\endgroup}
```

This might answer the *intended* question in a straightforward manner.

Any color model could be chosen instead of gray, but it's not obvious why that'd be desired.